# Blew a bulb, not the breaker, but now there's no power to the ceiling box

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I installed a new chandelier that worked initially, then a loose wire in the socket blew the bulb. I re-wired the socket, but now there seems to be no power. I have a current tester, not a meter and there seems to be no power in the box whatsoever. The breaker wasn't tripped. The only curve ball is that there is a main switch in the room as well as another switch with a dimmer. Both have to be on for it to work, though you can turn off with either. I've tried switching both on and off and can't get anything to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It could be your dimmer was a casualty of the initial problem - the electronics can be a bit sensitive to a sudden surge.

Comment: Agreed, the newer dimmers for LEDs are pretty sensitive, try to remove that and test with a single pole switch to confirm. Or test the dimmer switch if you can get a multimeter.

Comment: You say the breaker isn't tripped. Did you turn it off and then on anyway? Some breakers are not obvious that they have tripped.

Comment: maybe you trippesd a GFCI that you don;t know about